# How can ı do zoom with touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I was using windows 11.I could zoom and remove with 2 finger on touchpad. I use ubuntu 20.04 but now ı can't do this. Can you help me ? Is there any code or application for this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touchégg is an app that runs in the background and transform the gestures you make on your touchpad or touchscreen into visible actions in your desktop.

See `touchegg` at https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

Enable GNOME Shell multi-touch gestures on X11 with this extension.

See `X11 Gestures` at https://github.com/JoseExposito/gnome-shell-extension-x11gestures

The desktop application to configure Touchégg

See `touche` at https://github.com/JoseExposito/touche

**Note**: This requires X11, and won't work in Wayland.

Comment: Thanks your comment. I'ts work.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear from the OP's question which display server it used but, as of now, pinch to zoom gesture works automatically with Wayland.